# Continue Countdown Timer after visitor leaves website

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

My timer starts on window load. After a visitor closes my website page the timer pauses. If the visitor opens the same page (with timer) after 10 hours, the timer starts from the same time where it had paused earlier.

I want to create a 3 hour timer that **starts when website page is loaded** and that **keeps ticking in the background** even if the visitor is not currently visiting my website page.

I wish to redirect the visitor to another page say "amazon.com" after this 3 hour timer has expired, if he visits the website AFTER 3 hours.

```js
function countdown() {
  time = parseInt(localStorage.time);

  if(isNaN(time) || time > (38 * 60)) {
    //alert("An error occured: time left variable is corrupted, resetting timer");
    localStorage.time = 38 * 60;
    countdown();
    return null;
  }

  if(time <= 0) {
    alert("Your Timer Has Run Out! We Still Got 2 Discount Copies Left, Hurry Up!");
    return null;
  }

  var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timeleft');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(timers, function(timer) {
    timer.innerText = formatTime(time);
  })

  time--;
  localStorage.time = time;
  setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  seconds = time - minutes * 60;

  if(String(seconds).length == 1) {
    return String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds);
  }

  return String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds);
}

window.onload = function() {
  countdown();
}
```

```html
<font size="+34"><div class="timeleft"></div></font>
```

Comment: First, this sounds like an awful idea and if you were to do this I would actively boycott your annoying website.  Second, you do realize that JavaScript runs in a page, right? How do you propose to run code that isn’t there (ie when the user closes the page, there’s no JavaScript)?

Comment: These two requirements are incompatible: _"even if the visitor is not currently visiting my website"_ and _"I wish to redirect the visitor to another page"_.

Comment: I think perhaps the intent is to redirect to Amazon once the site is visited *after* the initial 3-hour window

Comment: Don't store the time remaining in `localStorage`, store the datetime of when the user first visited the page, and then base your calculations on that.

Comment: Yes, the intent is to redirect the person to another page...after timer has expired...if he visits the website AFTER 3 hour...if he doesn't visits the website then redirecting him is not an issue.

Comment: Still just an awful user experience.  I know how to do this, but I'm actively not going to answer because it's such a bad idea.

Comment: @Paul, my website is not annoying, i am just giving a vague idea of what i want to do...believe me there is much more to it.

Comment: @harsher taking away a users agency via an auto redirect to a third party site is the soul of bad design

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just store the start time in `localStorage`, and compare it to the current time whenever the page is loaded:

```
function startOrRedirect () {
  const startTime = localStorage.getItem('startTime')

  if (startTime) {
    const date1 = new Date(parseInt(startTime))
    const date2 = new Date()
    const hours = Math.abs(date1 - date2) / 36e5;

    if (hours >= 3) {
      redirect()
    }
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('startTime', Date.now)
    setTimeout(redirect, 1000 * 60 * 60)
  }
}

function redirect () {
  window.location = 'https://amazon.com'
}

window.onload = startOrRedirect
```